# searchMemory function in pykd

Tags: windbg, pykd

I'm trying to understand how to use the `searchMemory()` function in pykd extension for windbg.

The [documentation](https://pykd.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PYKD%200.3.%20API%20Reference&referringTitle=Documentation#searchMemory) says the following:

```
Function searchMemory

searchMemory( (long)arg1, (int)arg2, (list)arg3) -> int :
Search in virtual memory

C++ signature :
unsigned __int64 searchMemory(unsigned __int64,unsigned long,class boost::python::list)

searchMemory( (long)arg1, (int)arg2, (str)arg3) -> int :
Search in virtual memory

C++ signature :
unsigned __int64 searchMemory(unsigned __int64,unsigned long,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)
```

Does someone know what the arguments are and how should I use this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that there are 2 overloads of the same method:

```
searchMemory( (long)arg1, (int)arg2, (list)arg3) -> int
```

and

```
searchMemory( (long)arg1, (int)arg2, (str)arg3) -> int
```

- `arg1` is the start address or offset at which to start the search,
- `arg2` is the length or amount of memory to search and
- `arg3` is the search term, which can be

  - a string (`std::string`) or
  - a list (of `char`)
- the return value is an offset again, certainly the offset of the first occurrence, so to find the next occurrence, you have to search again

I have interpreted all this from the sources in [pymemaccess.cpp [Codeplex]](https://pykd.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#branch/0.3.x/pykd/pymemaccess.cpp) and never used it myself yet.

I'm neither very familiar with C++ nor with Python and even worse for the mapping between the two, but IMHO the `std::string` is a string of bytes and not Unicode characters, so you can put arbitraty bytes in there. It should also be suitable for ASCII search. But you might have to fiddle a bit for UTF-16 / UCS text. The same probably applies for the list of `char`, because it's not declared as `wchar_t`.